# Test if a regexp does not match the beginning of a string without using .nil?

Tags: ruby, regex, casting

I'm testing some strings to make sure they start with a letter:

```
name =~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/
```

but since in Ruby this evaluates to either `nil` or `0` and both cast to false, I need to put an additional `.nil?` test:

```
if(name =~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/).nil? ...
```

Is this the proper way or am I missing something?

*EDIT:*
Thanks for the replies, in my ignorance I made wrong assumptions, oversimplified the example. It should read (note the negation):

```
name !=~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/

irb(main):001:0> a = "abc"
=> "abc" 
irb(main):006:0> (a !=~/\Aabc/)
=> true
irb(main):007:0> (a !=~/\Ab/)
=> true
```

Comment: So basicly, you want to return `true` if name doesn't match your pattern?

Comment: Exactly - I am looking for a "does-not-match" operator. It seems it's not exactly the negation of the regulat `=~` when it comes to the `\A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but since in Ruby this evaluates to either nil or 0 and both cast to false

wrong, only `nil` (and `false`, to be precise) are treated as `false` in conditionals. `0` is treated as `true`. So

```
if name =~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/
```

is perfectly ok.

About your edited question, you're not allowed to add exclamation sign (`!`) to any operator to make it negated operator. There's no such operator (BTW, these 'operators' are actually [methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-3D-7E)) as `!=~`, so to achieve your goal. you should do:

```
if !(name =~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/)
```

or you can use `unless` instead:

```
unless name =~ /\A[a-zA-Z].*/
```

Comment: Just found: there's the operator: `!~` and it seems to do the job.